# EOF (End Of File) expexted error in output XML after XSL transformation

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, eof

I have "EOF Expexted" error in output XML after XSL transformation.
Question: What i need to do with this XSLT to get correct output?

Input XML:

```
<RowSet>
<Row>
     <msg_id>1</msg_id>
     <doc_id>1</doc_id>
     <doc_version>1</doc_version>
  </Row>
  <Row>
     <msg_id>2</msg_id>
     <doc_id>1</doc_id>
     <doc_version>2</doc_version>
  </Row>
    <Row>
     <msg_id>3</msg_id>
     <doc_id>1</doc_id>
     <doc_version>3</doc_version>
  </Row>
      <Row>
     <msg_id>4</msg_id>
     <doc_id>2</doc_id>
     <doc_version>1</doc_version>
  </Row>
<RowSet>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kRowByDocId" match="Row" use="doc_id"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select=
      "Row[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kRowByDocId', doc_id)[1])]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Row">
     <xsl:for-each select="key('kRowByDocId',doc_id)">
      <xsl:sort select="doc_version" data-type="number" order="descending"/>

      <xsl:if test="position() = 1"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output that i'm getting now (with EOF error):

```
<Row>
   <msg_id>3</msg_id>
   <doc_id>1</doc_id>
   <doc_version>3</doc_version>
</Row>
<Row>
   <msg_id>4</msg_id>
   <doc_id>2</doc_id>
   <doc_version>1</doc_version>
</Row>
```

Correct output must be something like this:

```
 <RowSet>
    <Row>
     <msg_id>3</msg_id>
     <doc_id>1</doc_id>
     <doc_version>3</doc_version>
   </Row>
      <Row>
     <msg_id>4</msg_id>
     <doc_id>2</doc_id>
     <doc_version>1</doc_version>
  </Row>
  <RowSet>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple. If you want to output a **Rowset** element, you just to need to output one in your template that matches the root element

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
   <RowSet>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Row[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kRowByDocId', doc_id)[1])]"/>
   </RowSet>
</xsl:template>
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to hardcode the **RowSet** element, you can just use **xsl:copy** to copy whatever the root element is:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Row[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kRowByDocId', doc_id)[1])]"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```